# Force T-SQL query to be case sensitive in MS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case-sensitive

I have a table that originates in an old legacy system that was case senstive, in particular a status column where 's' = 'Schedule import' and 'S' = 'Schedule management'. This table eventually makes its way into a SQL Server 2000 database which I can query against. My query is relatively simple just going for counts...

```
Select trans_type, count(1) from mytable group by trans_type
```

This is grouping the counts for 'S' along with the 's' counts. Is there any way to force a query to be cap sensitive? I have access to both SQL Server 2000 and 2005 environments to run this, however have limited admin capability on the server (so I can't set server attributes)... I guess I could move the data to my local and setup something on my local where I have full access to server options, but would prefer a tsql solution.

Comment: `alter database your_database collate Latin1_General_CS_AS`

Comment: SQL Server 2003 ?? I only know 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 ....

Comment: Unfortunately lack permissions to alter the table pascal, though I think that would work

Comment: lol sorry :P    I ment 2000/2005.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
select trans_type collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, count(*)
from mytable
group by trans_type collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

You can do this with `=`, `like`, and other operators as well. Note that you must modify the select list because you are no longer grouping by `trans_type`, you are now grouping by `trans_type collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`. Kind of a gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

Can you introduce a trans_type_ascii column with the ascii value of the trans_type and group on that instead?  Or any other column you can use (isUpperCase) to distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks Beth. I can't alter existing tables, but creating a temp table and loading it with the ascii values...that could work. There are other captial vs small values in the table (T and t for example)...I wonder if a case statement could handle it.  As psuedo code, case when type = 'T' then case when isuppercase(type) = 1 then 'T' else 't'.     I'll give a try anbd see what happens