# Case insensitive search query getting error: COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

I'm working on a project where I need to add search functionality to fields with special characters. Unfortunately, the fields that I need to search on were not encoded properly.

I want to search a field for the word **kèku** but only have to type the word **keku** (no accents).

The problem arises that fields are returning stuff like **WÃ¨mi kÃ¨ku sapÃ«lee.** instead of **Wèmi kèku sapëlee.**

I have fixed that by running the following query:

```
select CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(text USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8) as 'textlenape'
from samples_lenape where text_english like '%bright%'
```

That returns the text I want, but when I want to make it case insensitive by adding `collate utf8_general_ci` to the end of my query, I get the following error:

`COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'`

If I don't collate the query results, I cannot search for **keku** because I get an empty result set. Any ideas on how I need to convert this to be able to do a case-insensitive search? I don't want to alter the table data because the rest of the site will presumably break if I do so.

Comment: What charset have you defined for your connection?

Comment: I hit this error in the past, though it was on MSSQL 2005...it may be of some help to you (sorry if it isn't)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859085/force-t-sql-query-to-be-case-sensitive-in-ms

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the config of this app that the char set is changed, so I assume it is UTF-8. How would I check?

Comment: In your connection of the app query for `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'` the relevant variables are `character_set_client`, `character_set_connection` and `character_set_results`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to select everything and do the conversion/collation in my `WHERE` clause.

```
select * 
from samples_lenape 
where CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(text USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8) like _utf8 '%keku%' 
collate utf8_general_ci
```